# Python does not use locale from environment

Tags: python, locale

I have a python program ([jrnl](http://jrnl.sh/)) that should print the day of the week as text in German. However, it always prints the English name.

Here is the output of `locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

You can see that `LC_TIME` is set to `de_DE.UTF-8`. But when I start python this locale is not set:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
(None, None)
```

So my week day is shown in English:

```
>>> from time import gmtime, strftime
>>> strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())
'Monday, 15 Jan 2018 20:22:30 +0000'
```

What do I have to do for python to use the system locale?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [`locale` module *background* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#background-details-hints-tips-and-caveats):

> Initially, when a program is started, the locale is the `C` locale, no matter what the user’s preferred locale is.

You need to explicitly *set* the locale using [`locale.setlocale()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale); use the empty string to indicate that the user configuration needs to be used:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, '')
```

This is standard behaviour; the underlying C-level locale system [explicitly starts in the `C` locale](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.11.1.1p4) regardless of environment variables, as you can't assume that the current program actually wants or needs to honour user settings.

Comment: So if I have a python app I want to use (and don't want to change the code) then I'm out of luck if the locale is not set by the app? I can't define some environment variable right before starting the app to set the local? Seems like I need to contact the developer and ask him/her to add `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, '')`...

Comment: The locale is a global setting in the executable, and Python is highly dynamic. I don’t know what app you are using but I’d expect it to be fairly easy to wrap it or otherwise cause additional code to be executed that sets the locale. The latter can be done via `site.py` or a strategically placed `.pth` file for example.

Comment: But asking the developer is probably the best way as then other users would benefit too, yes.